# How to create an ArrayList<Double>?

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment for class that requires me to create a class that extends `ArrayList<Double>`. However I cannot make an `ArrayList<Double>` without getting an error.

I created a new class to try and test it and it still doesn't work. Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class imSad {

   ArrayList<Double> var = new ArrayList<Double>();

   var.add(double 15.0);

   var.add(15.0);
```

However this gives me the error : Syntax Error on token "15.0" invalid VariableDeclaratorID
and Syntax Error on token "add" Identifier expected after this token.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried searching it but I'm having trouble finding much on arraylists of doubles.

Comment: var.add(new Double(15.0f)); var.add(15.0f);

Comment: Why would you expect this line - `var.add(double 15.0);` to compile?

Comment: Just remove the word `double` from before `15.0`.  Everything else is perfect.

Comment: **I've tried searching it but I'm having trouble finding much on arraylists of doubles.** Typing 'arraylist of doubles' (google) gives you examples when clicking just the second link - took me ~10s to find.

Answer (score 3):

the cast is wrong.

use

```
var.add((double) 15.0);
```

or

```
var.add(15.0d);
```

or better, by default

```
var.add(15.0);
```

Comment: Isn't `15.0` a `double` type by default?

Comment: Don't do this.  `15.0` is already a `double`.  It's completely redundant either to cast it, or to affix the `d`.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna cast it, you should write

```
var.add((double) 15.0);
```

or

```
var.add(15.0d);
```

if you write

```
var.add(double 15.0);
```

it is a declaration of a new double, which you will name `15.0` (which is not valid, because you can't start a variable name with a number and it can not contain a dot.)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value to a double variable and then add it.

```
double val = 15.0; // create a double variable
var.add(val); // add it to the list
..
var.add(15.0); // add it without creating a new double variable, which you already did
```

Also, by default *15.0* is `double` and thus you need not cast it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cast to write double literals in Java; all floating-point literals are double by default (JLS7, 3.10.2).  So just writing

```
var.add(15.0);
```

is entirely sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just add doubles like this, you don't need casting:

```
var.add(15.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class YouShouldResearch{

public static void main(String ar[]) {
     ArrayList<Double> var = new ArrayList<Double>();
     var.add(15.0);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var.add(15.0);
```

should be OK. Or

```
var.add((double)15.0);
```